# how to disable database log?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using **log4j** for getting log but I did not set debug log at time. I need to stop it. how could I do? I tried changes in **log4j.property** file

I am using following **log4j** property file

```html
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


#Log levels
#log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,R,ERROR,WARN
## Appender Configuration
#log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
## Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number
#log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n


# LOG4J daily rolling log files configuration
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/var/log/dpdocter/logs.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

and stop to get this

```html
14:37:36.686 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.686 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5797322be4b063668d11440f"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.687 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5797323ee4b063668d114411"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.687 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.687 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5797323ee4b063668d114411"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.688 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973247e4b063668d114413"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.688 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.688 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973247e4b063668d114413"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.688 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973253e4b063668d114415"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.688 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.688 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973253e4b063668d114415"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.689 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "579734ebe4b063668d114417"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.689 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.689 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "579734ebe4b063668d114417"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.689 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "579734f5e4b063668d114419"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.690 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.690 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "579734f5e4b063668d114419"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.690 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "579735c3e4b063668d11441b"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.690 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.690 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "579735c3e4b063668d11441b"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.691 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "579735cbe4b063668d11441d"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.691 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.691 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "579735cbe4b063668d11441d"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.691 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "579735d5e4b063668d11441f"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.691 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.691 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "579735d5e4b063668d11441f"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.692 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "579735dee4b063668d114421"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.692 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.692 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "579735dee4b063668d114421"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.692 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "579735e8e4b063668d114423"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.692 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.692 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "579735e8e4b063668d114423"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.693 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973604e4b063668d114425"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.693 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.693 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973604e4b063668d114425"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.693 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5797361de4b063668d114427"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.694 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.694 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5797361de4b063668d114427"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.694 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973624e4b063668d114429"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.694 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.694 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973624e4b063668d114429"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.695 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5797362ce4b063668d11442b"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.695 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.695 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5797362ce4b063668d11442b"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.695 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973633e4b063668d11442d"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.695 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.695 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973633e4b063668d11442d"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.696 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973660e4b063668d11442f"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.696 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.696 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973660e4b063668d11442f"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.696 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5797366ae4b063668d114431"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.697 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.697 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5797366ae4b063668d114431"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.697 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973672e4b063668d114433"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.697 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.697 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973672e4b063668d114433"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.698 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5797367ae4b063668d114435"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.698 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.698 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5797367ae4b063668d114435"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.698 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973683e4b063668d114437"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.698 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.698 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973683e4b063668d114437"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.699 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5797368ee4b063668d114439"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.699 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.699 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5797368ee4b063668d114439"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.699 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57973bd9e4b063668d11443b"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.699 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.699 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57973bd9e4b063668d11443b"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.700 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57974122e4b063668d11443d"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.700 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.700 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57974122e4b063668d11443d"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.700 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5797cb5be4b04a8410fba36f"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.700 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.700 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5797cb5be4b04a8410fba36f"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.701 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57984f75e4b063668d11443f"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DiagramsCollection in collection: diagrams_cl
14:37:36.701 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.701 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57984f75e4b063668d11443f"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.diagrams_cl
14:37:36.702 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "579e39bfe4b092ad8bd3c010"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DrugCollection in collection: drug_cl
14:37:36.702 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.702 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "579e39bfe4b092ad8bd3c010"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.drug_cl
14:37:36.702 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5799ced7e4b0a3fc9797ebfe"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DrugCollection in collection: drug_cl
14:37:36.702 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.702 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5799ced7e4b0a3fc9797ebfe"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.drug_cl
14:37:36.703 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57d10384e4b03ba54ce6bad3"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection in collection: doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.703 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.703 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57d10384e4b03ba54ce6bad3"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.704 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "57f6231a84aee15fa97095fa"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection in collection: doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.704 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.704 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57f6231a84aee15fa97095fa"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.707 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.c.m.e.AbstractMongoEventListener - onAfterLoad({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57f6231a84aee15fa97095fa"} , "_class" : "com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection" , "drugId" : { "$oid" : "55f10a9de4b0088488b699fe"} , "doctorId" : { "$oid" : "57a57621e4b0dd18e91e35a9"} , "hospitalId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c2"} , "locationId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c3"} , "rankingCount" : 1 , "discarded" : false , "updatedTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-06T10:10:34.302Z"}})
14:37:36.730 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'validatingMongoEventListener'
14:37:36.731 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.c.m.e.AbstractMongoEventListener - onAfterConvert({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57f6231a84aee15fa97095fa"} , "_class" : "com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection" , "drugId" : { "$oid" : "55f10a9de4b0088488b699fe"} , "doctorId" : { "$oid" : "57a57621e4b0dd18e91e35a9"} , "hospitalId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c2"} , "locationId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c3"} , "rankingCount" : 1 , "discarded" : false , "updatedTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-06T10:10:34.302Z"}}, DoctorDrugCollection [id=57f6231a84aee15fa97095fa, drugId=55f10a9de4b0088488b699fe, doctorId=57a57621e4b0dd18e91e35a9, hospitalId=5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c2, locationId=5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c3, rankingCount=1, discarded=false, genericCodes=null, duration=null, dosage=null, dosageTime=null, direction=null, genericNames=null])
14:37:36.731 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "55f10a9de4b0088488b699fe"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DrugCollection in collection: drug_cl
14:37:36.731 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.731 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "55f10a9de4b0088488b699fe"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.drug_cl
14:37:36.734 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "580cb2a4e4b02e982129cb1d"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection in collection: doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.734 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.734 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "580cb2a4e4b02e982129cb1d"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.735 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.c.m.e.AbstractMongoEventListener - onAfterLoad({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "580cb2a4e4b02e982129cb1d"} , "_class" : "com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection" , "drugId" : { "$oid" : "580c7e18e4b075585677d800"} , "doctorId" : { "$oid" : "5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b74e"} , "hospitalId" : { "$oid" : "5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b750"} , "locationId" : { "$oid" : "5794add3e4b01f1d73f9b751"} , "rankingCount" : 2 , "discarded" : false , "createdTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-23T12:52:52.025Z"} , "updatedTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-23T12:52:52.025Z"}})
14:37:36.736 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.c.m.e.AbstractMongoEventListener - onAfterConvert({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "580cb2a4e4b02e982129cb1d"} , "_class" : "com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection" , "drugId" : { "$oid" : "580c7e18e4b075585677d800"} , "doctorId" : { "$oid" : "5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b74e"} , "hospitalId" : { "$oid" : "5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b750"} , "locationId" : { "$oid" : "5794add3e4b01f1d73f9b751"} , "rankingCount" : 2 , "discarded" : false , "createdTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-23T12:52:52.025Z"} , "updatedTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-23T12:52:52.025Z"}}, DoctorDrugCollection [id=580cb2a4e4b02e982129cb1d, drugId=580c7e18e4b075585677d800, doctorId=5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b74e, hospitalId=5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b750, locationId=5794add3e4b01f1d73f9b751, rankingCount=2, discarded=false, genericCodes=null, duration=null, dosage=null, dosageTime=null, direction=null, genericNames=null])
14:37:36.737 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "580c7e18e4b075585677d800"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DrugCollection in collection: drug_cl
14:37:36.737 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.737 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "580c7e18e4b075585677d800"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.drug_cl
14:37:36.742 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "580cb2f0e4b02e982129cb1f"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection in collection: doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.742 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.742 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "580cb2f0e4b02e982129cb1f"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.746 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.c.m.e.AbstractMongoEventListener - onAfterLoad({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "580cb2f0e4b02e982129cb1f"} , "_class" : "com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection" , "drugId" : { "$oid" : "580c7ddbe4b075585677d7fe"} , "doctorId" : { "$oid" : "5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b74e"} , "hospitalId" : { "$oid" : "5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b750"} , "locationId" : { "$oid" : "5794add3e4b01f1d73f9b751"} , "rankingCount" : 1 , "discarded" : false , "createdTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-23T12:54:08.326Z"} , "updatedTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-23T12:54:08.326Z"}})
14:37:36.747 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.c.m.e.AbstractMongoEventListener - onAfterConvert({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "580cb2f0e4b02e982129cb1f"} , "_class" : "com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection" , "drugId" : { "$oid" : "580c7ddbe4b075585677d7fe"} , "doctorId" : { "$oid" : "5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b74e"} , "hospitalId" : { "$oid" : "5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b750"} , "locationId" : { "$oid" : "5794add3e4b01f1d73f9b751"} , "rankingCount" : 1 , "discarded" : false , "createdTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-23T12:54:08.326Z"} , "updatedTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-23T12:54:08.326Z"}}, DoctorDrugCollection [id=580cb2f0e4b02e982129cb1f, drugId=580c7ddbe4b075585677d7fe, doctorId=5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b74e, hospitalId=5794add2e4b01f1d73f9b750, locationId=5794add3e4b01f1d73f9b751, rankingCount=1, discarded=false, genericCodes=null, duration=null, dosage=null, dosageTime=null, direction=null, genericNames=null])
14:37:36.747 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "580c7ddbe4b075585677d7fe"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DrugCollection in collection: drug_cl
14:37:36.747 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.747 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "580c7ddbe4b075585677d7fe"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.drug_cl
14:37:36.749 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "581092d6e4b0882022380aae"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection in collection: doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.749 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.749 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "581092d6e4b0882022380aae"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.doctor_drug_cl
14:37:36.750 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.c.m.e.AbstractMongoEventListener - onAfterLoad({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "581092d6e4b0882022380aae"} , "_class" : "com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection" , "drugId" : { "$oid" : "5803a53ae4b009e92cae5484"} , "doctorId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c0"} , "hospitalId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c2"} , "locationId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c3"} , "rankingCount" : 1 , "discarded" : false , "updatedTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-26T11:26:14.900Z"}})
14:37:36.751 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.c.m.e.AbstractMongoEventListener - onAfterConvert({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "581092d6e4b0882022380aae"} , "_class" : "com.dpdocter.collections.DoctorDrugCollection" , "drugId" : { "$oid" : "5803a53ae4b009e92cae5484"} , "doctorId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c0"} , "hospitalId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c2"} , "locationId" : { "$oid" : "5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c3"} , "rankingCount" : 1 , "discarded" : false , "updatedTime" : { "$date" : "2016-10-26T11:26:14.900Z"}}, DoctorDrugCollection [id=581092d6e4b0882022380aae, drugId=5803a53ae4b009e92cae5484, doctorId=5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c0, hospitalId=5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c2, locationId=5794af08e4b01f1d73f9b7c3, rankingCount=1, discarded=false, genericCodes=null, duration=null, dosage=null, dosageTime=null, direction=null, genericNames=null])
14:37:36.752 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "id" : { "$oid" : "5803a53ae4b009e92cae5484"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.DrugCollection in collection: drug_cl
14:37:36.752 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
14:37:36.752 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5803a53ae4b009e92cae5484"}} in db.collection: dpdocter_db.drug_cl
14:37:36.753 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.d.m.r.q.StringBasedMongoQuery - Created query { "state" : { "$ne" : "EXPIRED"}} for null fields.
14:37:36.764 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - find using query: { "state" : { "$ne" : "EXPIRED"}} fields: null for class: class com.dpdocter.collections.OTPCollection in collection: otp_cl
14:37:36.764 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[dpdocter_db]
```

Comment: I hope your log4j.property file is named log4j.propert**ies** instead?

Answer (score 0):

From: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/reference/management/logging/

"By default, logging is enabled via the popular SLF4J API. The use of SLF4J is optional; the driver will use SLF4J if the driver detects the presence of SLF4J in the classpath. Otherwise, the driver will fall back to JUL (java.util.logging)"

So you need  to make sure that you have slf4j configured over log4j to be able to apply log4j options. 
Or if you don't like to have slf4j in your project the only option is configuring JUL.